# Cron job creates empty files

Tags: bash

I want to preface that I am a newbie that picked up shell scripting 2 weeks ago.

Hey guys I need help with something, hope someone can point me in the right direction. I have a script that works when I run it from the command line but every time I run it with a crontab, the output is a few empty files. Does anyone know why?
That's the code down there

```
#!/bin/bash

#Provide an IP address as an argument to use nmap
#make sure to add the full range with (0-225 or 0/24) at the end

IPADDRESS=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')

network-scan(){
if [ $1 ]
then
  sudo nmap -sn $1
else
  sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0-255
fi
}

#Scan the whole network and only prints the IP addresses minus your own
#Sends the IP addresses to a file
network-scan | grep -i 'Nmap scan report' | \
    sed 's/\ /\n/g'|sed 's/(//g'|sed 's/)//g' | \
    grep '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' | grep -v ${IPADDRESS} > ip_addresses

#Scan the whole network and only prints the MAC addresses
#Sends the MAC addresses to a file
network-scan | grep -i 'MAC Address:' | \
    awk '{print $3}' > mac_addresses

#Put the IP and MAC addresses in the same file
paste ip_addresses mac_addresses | \
    column -s $'\t' -t > "scan_$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S)"

#Notify that a file with the IP and MAC addresses has been created on the Desktop
echo "A file containing the results of the scan has been created on the Desktop"

exit 0
```

Comment: You haven't set or navigated to any path so it will create output files in user's home directory; by which cron is scheduled. Just mentioning it to make sure you are checking in same place. Kindly do confirm on same, thank you.

Comment: That's not the issue , because even when I put the script in the home directory it does the same thing. The cron job has a valid path otherwise it would not work

Comment: No, I didn't mean that cron is having wrong path, what I meant is: please make sure you are checking output files in your home directory only

Comment: Is the cron job running as root (in which case `sudo` is unnecessary and irrelevant) or as a normal user (in which case `sudo` will probably fail because it can't ask for the password it needs to allow promotion to root)? Also, is the `nmap` binary in one of the directories in cron's `PATH` (generally just `/usr/bin:/bin` by default)? If neither of those is the problem, standard first troubleshooting step is to capture output & errors from the job by adding something like `>>/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1` to the crontab entry, then look in that file for indications of what's going wrong.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I think I get what you are saying and like I said I am a newbie so I don't know how to do that. I want the cronjob to creates the output on the Desktop but it instead sends stuff in my home directory as you said. It's another issue that I don't know how to solve

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
network-scan | grep
```

without passing any parameter.
Hence network-scan function always using

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0-255
```

1. when you run it from command line are you passing any parameter ?
2. echo $IPADDRESS inside the script when executing at cron and at command line for debugging.
3. 

```
network-scan | grep -i 'Nmap scan report' | \
    sed 's/\ /\n/g'|sed 's/(//g'|sed 's/)//g' | \
    grep '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' | grep -v ${IPADDRESS}
```

Since you are obtaining empty output, validate each command and append(test) each OR operators to know where it is removing required output.

Comment: that's the thing, everything works as intended when I run it from the command line. There is something not working when I run it through crontab and that's what I cannot figure out